# Can't use rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rake

When I try to apply migrations through **rake db:migrate**, I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 12.0.0, but your 
Gemfile requires rake 10.4.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command 
may solve this.
/home/jeyjeyanischixx/CaprisePro/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jeyjeyanischixx/CaprisePro/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jeyjeyanischixx/CaprisePro/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jeyjeyanischixx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
```

Then when I add bundle exec before this command, I get this:

```
Could not find nokogiri-1.8.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

But I have already installed all the gems successfully (including nokogiri and rake in two versions(10.4.2 and 12.0.0)).

Rails: 4.2.10;
Ruby: 2.4.1

Comment: have you tried: `bundle exec rake db:migrate`?

Comment: Remove rake gem from gemfile ?

Comment: Emu, yes, I've tried. But I have the above problem.

Comment: Your gemfile is messed up. delete gemfil.lock and redo the budle

Comment: D1ceWard, I have the following lines in my gemfile:

    gem 'rake', '10.4.2'
   #gem 'rake', '12.0.0'

Comment: remove gemfile.lock and install bundle again.

Comment: Ok. The issue has been resolved. Thanks, Hardik and Ravi :) I've just uninstalled and installed again rake-10.4.2